# Order Bootstrap Grid by column for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

I have a bootstrap grid with 2 rows and 3 columns. It looks on desktop like this:

```
 |A|B|C|
 |D|E|F|
```

If i switch to mobile it looks like:

```
|A|
|B|
|C|
|D|
|E|
|F|
```

But i would like that it looks like this:

```
|A|
|D|
|B|
|E|
|C|
|F|
```

So it should first list all items of column 1 followed by column 2 and so on.

Is there any trick which allows me that the grid behaves like i want it to?

```
 <div class="container">
          <div class = "d-flex row">
              <div class="text-muted col-sm-2">A</div>
              <div class="text-muted col-sm-2">B</div>
              <div class="text-muted col-sm">C</div>

            </div>
            <div class = "d-flex row">
              <div class="article-content col-sm-2">D</div>
              <div class="article-content col-sm-2">E</div>
              <div class="article-content col-sm">F</div>
            
          
      </div>
```

Best regards

Comment: I do not know of a bootstrap solution for this, but I believe I was able to accomplish what you are wanting with CSS grid and grid-template-areas: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/jOyyxKa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of Columns from the Bootstrap layout check it from [Bootstrap layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/)

So you can make one row with three columns every column has 2 rows.

```html
 <div class="container">

          <div class = "d-flex row">

            <div class="col-sm-4">   
               <div class="text-muted col-sm-2">A</div>
               <div class="article-content col-sm-2">D</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4">   
              <div class="text-muted col-sm-2">B</div>
              <div class="article-content col-sm-2">E</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4">   
              <div class="text-muted col-sm-2">C</div>
              <div class="article-content col-sm-2">F</div>
            </div>

         </div>   
    </div>
```

So it will be one big row with 3 columns like in this picture [image]

In the mobile layout Bootstrap grid system will remain the one big row but will put the 3 columns under each other to fit the screen size like this

[image]

You still have the control over "col-sm-2" to control the size of each column at each screen size as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

That should work
(As long as they all have the same height)

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class = "col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="text-muted row">A</div>
          <div class="article-content row">D</div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="text-muted row">B</div>
          <div class="article-content row">E</div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="text-muted row">C</div>
          <div class="article-content row">F</div>
      </div>           
  </div>
```